# instalar driver de audio

Tags: linux

es mi primera vez instalando un OS, instalé parrot, la mayoria de drivers fueron instalados automaticamente, a excepción del audio,  no sé mucho del tema, pero me gustaría saber como verificar o solucionar esto ya que he estado buscando por internet sobre como activar el audio o instalar driver de audio y no he tenido éxito, espero y me puedan ayudar, repito voy iniciando con esto. gracias

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask], para mejorar tu pregunta y que esta sea bien recibida por la comunidad incrementando las chances de obtener respuestas útiles. Lamentablemente tu pregunta no parece ser consistente con la temática del sitio tal como se define en: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nada mas arrancar el linux, ejecuta este comando:

**dmesg**

Pega aquí el resultado o busca en el algo relativo a tu tarjeta de sonido. Para saber qué versión/marca reconoce. Ahi te va a decir por ejemplo "soundblaster...333"

Busca también en **/var/log/messages** algo relativo a "soundblaster...333" o lo que te ha dado el comando dmesg y sobre ello busca en google.

Recuerdo que si instalas el paquete ALSA te instala todo lo relativo a drivers/utilidades.